# How can i check if li selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make reservation system for test with HTML, CSS, JS. i have button next, i need to know if some one of li selected then it will be work, if no one li is selected then it must be show me alert.
There is code.

```
const staff = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alex Rosetta",
        "email": "alexyrosetta@egmail.com",
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/LJnNhRF/unsplash-279x-IHym-PYY.png",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Maria July",
        "email": "mariajuly@egmail.com",
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/3FhkswY/unsplash-IF9-TK5-Uy-KI.png",
    }
];
const services = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Oral hygiene",
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/XkRzNyr/Oval-2.png",
        "duration": "1 hour",
        "price": 50.00,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Implants",
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/Pr5m2kY/Oval-1.png",
        "duration": "1 hour 30 minutes",
        "price": 120.00,
    }
];





function getHTML(data) {
    return staff.map(obj => {
        const { id, name, email, image } = obj;
        return `
      <li class="repoFolder" data-value="${id}">
        <div class="doc-photo">
          <img src="${image}" alt="Image of ${name}" />
        </div>
        <div class="doc-infos">
          <p class="name">${name}</p>
          <p class="mail">${email}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    `;
    }).join('');
}

const list = document.querySelector(".myUl");
list.addEventListener('click', handleList);



list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getHTML(staff));


const items = list.querySelectorAll('.myUl li');


function handleList(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('li')) {
        const parent = e.target.closest('li');
        items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('my-class'));
        parent.classList.add('my-class');
    }
}
var next = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
next.addEventListener("click", myFunction2);
for (var i = 0; i < items2.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('.next-btn').onclick = function () {
        document.querySelector(".myUl li").forEach(item => item.classList.contains('my-class'));
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.add('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.remove('hide');

    };
}

function myFunction2(e) {
    if (document.querySelector(".myUl li").classList.contains('my-class')) {
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.add('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
        alert("hey")
    }
}
var lis = document.querySelector(".myUl li");
for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    console.log(lis[i].id);
    function myFunction2(e) {
    if (document.querySelector(".myUl li").classList.contains('my-class')) {
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.add('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
        alert("hey")
    }
}
}
```

I tried like this, but its working only for first li

```
var selected = document.querySelector(".myUl li");
selected.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.classList.contains('my-class')) {
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.add('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
        alert("hey")
    }
});
```

Can someone help please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "...one of li...selected"? The only kind of "select" that applies to `li` elements is text selection, which doesn't seem to be what you're askin about.

Comment: there is two li elements when i choose first, next button working. when i choose second one next button not working :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use querySelectorAll, then change ur code like this :)

```
function myFunction2(e) {
const liElements = document.querySelectorAll(".myUl li");
liElements.forEach(li => {
    if (li.classList.contains('my-class')) {
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('hide');
        document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.add('show');
        document.querySelector('.container2').classList.remove('hide');
    }
});
if (Array.from(liElements).filter(li => li.classList.contains('my-class')).length == 0) {
    alert("hey")
}
}
```

Comment: @user563597 u r welcome :)

Comment: Please pay attention to documentations : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace -> use `.classList.replace('show','hide')`